# How to convert nanoseconds to seconds using the TimeUnit enum?

Tags: java, timeunit

How to convert a value from nanoseconds to seconds?

Here's the code segment:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*; 
..

class Stamper { 

public static void main (String[] args) { 
long start = System.nanoTime(); 
//some try with nested loops 
long end = System.nanoTime(); 
long elapsedTime = end - start;

System.out.println("elapsed: " + elapsedTime + "nano seconds\n");

//convert to seconds 
TimeUnit seconds = new TimeUnit(); 
System.out.println("which is " + seconds.toSeconds(elapsedTime) + " seconds"); 
}}
```

The error is

```
Stamper.java:16:  enum types may not be instantiated.
```

What does this mean?

Comment: The error means that you can not instantiate the type `TimeUtil`, because it is an `enum` (enumerator). If you want to use `TimeUnit`, you should use `TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toSeconds(elapsedTime)` instead. Good luck!

Answer (score 217, accepted):

Well, you could just divide by 1,000,000,000:

```
long elapsedTime = end - start;
double seconds = (double)elapsedTime / 1_000_000_000.0;
```

If you use `TimeUnit` to convert, you'll get your result as a long, so you'll lose decimal precision but maintain whole number precision.

Comment: I would change make 1000000000 a double to force double precision division.

Comment: 1000000000.0 is already a double; a float constant would be 1000000000.0f.

Comment: But what if the number of nanoseconds in a second changes? :P

Comment: @geofftnz I hope this was joke.

Comment: Of course, this answer doesn't use the TimeUnit enum as requested.

Comment: This answer is now wrong - `convert()` and the `toFoo()` methods all return `long`s now http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html

Comment: Riking is not joking, this answer is now wrong in that TimeUnit methods return longs (not integers); the code sample still works, but is bad practice (a hard-coded 10-digit number is easy to mess up or change without noticing). pythonquick's answer below is the preferred expression.

Comment: @mbarrows However this answer is still *right* in that the `TimeUnit` solution results in a loss of specificity. `TimeUnit.SECONDS.convert(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);` will return `0`, not `0.5`. It simply depends on your use-case which of these is preferable.

Comment: @nbrooks A very good point, though in my experience, if you're reducing the granularity of your time units, it's either because you need it to be human readable or you don't care about that level of precision. Either usually means losing the decimal is fine.

Comment: Thoroughly agree with @nbrooks here. Using TimeUnit will not output fractions of a second, instead returning 0. If you don't want to use a hard coded 10 digit number then use something like 1E9.
For example : `double seconds = ((double) nanoseconds) / 1E9;`

I would do this every time as a personal preference.

Comment: Use this method over the TimeUnit Enum method if you would like fractions of a second.  Using the TimeUnit Enum doesn't even round to the nearest second, it essentially just chops off the fractions of a second. So 4.9999999, would simply be 4.

Comment: @geofftnz: That's why the "magic number" should be externalised and read from a 23-layer deep XML configuration file on each use.

Comment: @MarkKCowan static configuration files are deprecated, you should call the TimeConversion microservice.

Comment: @geofftnz no you should call a UnitConversionAdapter which proxies to the TimeConversion μservice

Answer (score 374):

## `TimeUnit` Enum

The following expression uses the [`TimeUnit`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html) enum (Java 5 and later) to convert from nanoseconds to seconds:

```
TimeUnit.SECONDS.convert(elapsedTime, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
```

Comment: Not that this method does not include fractions of a second. So 4.9999999, would simply be 4 seconds.

Comment: This is preferred because you should never write out 1 followed by a whole mess of 0's due to it being very error prone.

Comment: you can write it like this      elapsedTime = (end_time - start_time)/1e9;

Comment: If I stay 59 minutes and 50 seconds it still says 0h elapsed... Which is not ideal. So is there any way to make this method work with fractions?

Answer (score 61):

TimeUnit is an enum, so you can't create a new one.

The following will convert 1000000000000ns to seconds.

```
TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toSeconds(1000000000000L);
```

Comment: I believe it is 10e+9 not 1e+12!

Comment: This is a pretty late reply, but the number in the example isn’t the number of nanos in a second, it’s just a number to convert.  The whole idea is to not have to know those values.

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer. Using toXxx() is preferable to using convert() because with convert() it's not obvious which direction the conversion happens, whereas with toXxx() it is.

Answer (score 22):

To reduce verbosity, you can use a static import:

```
import static java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS;
```

-and henceforth just type

```
NANOSECONDS.toSeconds(elapsedTime);
```

Answer (score 7):

You should write :

```
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();        
    long estimatedTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
```

Assigning the endTime in a variable might cause a few nanoseconds. In this approach you will get the exact elapsed time.

And then:

```
TimeUnit.SECONDS.convert(estimatedTime, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
```

Answer (score 4):

This will convert a time to seconds in a double format, which is more precise than an integer value:

```
double elapsedTimeInSeconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(elapsedTime, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS) / 1000.0;
```

Answer (score 3):

**JDK9**+ solution using **java.time.Duration**

```
Duration.ofNanos(1_000_000L).toSeconds()
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#ofNanos-long-

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#toSeconds--

Answer (score 1):

In `Java 8` or `Kotlin`, I use `Duration.ofNanos(1_000_000_000)` like

```
val duration = Duration.ofNanos(1_000_000_000)
logger.info(String.format("%d %02dm %02ds %03d",
                elapse, duration.toMinutes(), duration.toSeconds(), duration.toMillis()))
```

Read more https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html