# Java : Total downloading time

Tags: java

I already start programming a code that download a file using Java 
but , I want to calculate the total time of downloading

I search but I only found it using  system.currenttimemillis()
but the output will be like this 
http://tinypic.com/r/2mgkt5k/5

I want to print output that can tell total time(in milli second)

Comment: I don't see a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like the below may be feasible here:

```
long a = System.nanoTime();

//Do your stuff

System.out.println("Total time taken: " + System.nanoTime() - a);
```

Comment: it's the same !

this is the output http://tinypic.com/r/23vysl5/5

i want the output to be like this 
http://tinypic.com/r/nyv7ue/5

one line only not more :(

Comment: My answer should give you the nanoseconds the process took, have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/924208/how-to-convert-nanoseconds-to-seconds-using-the-timeunit-enum also which may help you convert it into seconds

Answer (score 0):

try this http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/Stopwatch.java.html

that's very easy

```
Stopwatch st = new Stopwatch();

// Do something. In your case Upload image !

double time = st.elapsedTime(); // the result in millis

// Print time
```

This class is a part of stdlib.jar

Comment: it's the same !

this is the output http://tinypic.com/r/23vysl5/5

i want the output to be like this 
http://tinypic.com/r/nyv7ue/5

one line only not more :(